# intelliJ Issue Navigation in code comments

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, intellij-14

With IntelliJ IDEA you can search for a specified regex pattern in VCS checkin comments and have it linked to an issue tracker like YouTrack or JIRA.

**Is there a way to do this in the code comments?**  I know I can stick a huge URL in there and have that linked... but how about just the issue alone?  Ex:

```
// fix this string -- see ACME-2034
$someVar = 'some_problem';
```

Comment: you want to search code comments in your working directory or in the history of your VCS?

Comment: I know this isn't an answer, but writing ticket numbers in code is soooo 1980's. You don't need to do that! You can Annotate your code to see which line was modified, and the corresponding ticket number in the checkin comments.

Comment: I'm not talking about every ticket or anything, just on occasion.  Ex: some dev not familiar with a portion of code sees something strange and goes to fix it when he shouldn't (i.e., a code trap).  So we use comments to warn him.  I would simply like to stick some issue #'s in there so he can jump to more info quickly without opening VCS history.  Best practice?  Maybe not... but 1980s?

Comment: It's a great practice when reality turns out to be complicated, and it will happen with or without IDE support. Also, it could be nice to abuse it for JEP, RFC, etc. references...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Plugin `Tasks Navigation` from the Marketplace.

After you installed the Plugin, you'll have to add your Jira-Server to `Tools > Tasks > Servers`.
I simply added my Jira-server (e.g. `http://my-jira.my-domain.com:8080`) without Username and Passwort - I don't want those to be saved in Jira.

In `Tools > Tasks > Navigation` the check mark `Search for issues in comments` should already be set.

Now you can CTRL+Klick on anything that looks like a Jira-ID:

[image: Screenshot Open in Browser]

see also: Github-Home of the Plugin: https://github.com/VladRassokhin/intellij-tasks-navigate

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ now supports this in `Preferences | Version Control | Issue Navigation`.

[image: Screenshot of Issue Navigation preferences]

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-version-control-issue-navigation.html

Comment: This is issue navigation from commit messages. The author asked for this in code comments.

Comment: For me, doing this turns issues in code comments into links as well. Strange.

Comment: After having that set up (I wonder where it lost my previous settings which I had for years) now it seems to work again after restarting IJ

Answer (score 0):

The Issue Navigation supports code comments also, not just commit messages.

But it only works with regular grey comments, not with green PHPDoc comments.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-50454